# Minecraft- Connecting with a friend far away

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my cousin want to connect when shes at her house and im at mine. Is there a possible way we can connect

Comment: to each others world

Answer (score 1):

If you want to join another player's Minecraft world, you'll need to do a few steps.

First of all, you need to **friend** them. To do this, go into the "Friends" tab (After pressing the play button on the Title Screen) and select "Add friend". To add them as a friend, all you have to do is type in their Gamertag. This is pretty much what their name is in the game.

Once you do this, make sure that the other person does the same, but with your Gamertag (or your in game character name).

Then, open up a world, and they should be able to join it through the friends tab.

Answer (score -3):

https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8

That link will send you to the app store. I used to use the app until i got a pc and started playing the pc version

Answer (score -4):

You will need to setup a minecraft-pe server. You can use a free software called pocketmine https://www.pocketmine.net/

Comment: How would you use this program to solve the problem?  Just pointing at a piece of software that could do the trick, while a good start, isn't very helpful.  You need to add steps on how to use it for this to be a good answer.

Comment: The pocket-mine index has enough details to cover every question. Looks like downvoting is a sport for you.

Comment: And for answers to be valid here, you need to provide that information. This barely qualifies as an answer without it.

Comment: I am downvoting because this constitutes as a link only answer. please summarize what is in the link (particularly the instructions @Frank mentions) should the site go down and invalidate the answer (as the software can normally be found elsewhere)